# Clearing my browser

Tags: google-chrome

I am having problems accessing my online payslips, my company have said the problem is my end and need to clear my browser. I have been told that this will clear all my passwords for everything. Is this correct? as I am not willing to do this TIA

Comment: That depends on what you do. It could be a side effect.

Comment: Not an answer to your question but a possible workaround solution to your problem:
Why not access your payroll site in an incognito window before logging in? You can do this by pressing Ctrl+Alt+N This will leave you other passwords untouched.

Answer (score 1):

You can clear site specific data in Chrome by opening Chrome's DevTools by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd>. Find the `Application` tab along the top and then the `Clear Storage` option on the left.

If you're sure you want to clear that site's data then click the `Clear Site Data` button towards the bottom.

[image]

This will not clear any saved passwords (related to that site or otherwise.)